# How do I sort a slice by values of a map

Tags: sorting, go

Seems a basic question, but can't find a simple answer.

I have a slice:

```
[]string{"dog", "cat", "bird"}
```

What's the best way to sort it by looking up the sorting values in a map:

```
map[string]int{"dog": 2, "cat":3, "bird": 1}
```

So that the slice is ordered as below:

```
[]string{"bird", "dog", "cat"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement the [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) interface for a type that stores the data and the weights:

```
import "sort"

type WeightedStringSlice struct {
    Strings []string
    Weights map[string]int
}

func (s *WeightedStringSlice) Len() int {
    return len(s.Strings)
}

func (s *WeightedStringSlice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s.Weights[s.Strings[i]] < s.Weights[s.Strings[j]]
}

func (s *WeightedStringSlice) Swap(i, j int) {
    s.Strings[i], s.Strings[j] = s.Strings[j], s.Strings[i]
}
```

Then call [`sort.Sort`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort) on it:

```
data := WeightedStringSlice{
    Strings: []string{"dog", "cat", "bird"},
    Weights: map[string]int{"dog": 2, "cat": 3, "bird": 1},
}
sort.Sort(&data)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", data.Strings)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](https://play.golang.org/p/es3tynV6yw)</kbd>